# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined on post request

Tags: php, mysql, api, slim

I'm trying to write some data to a database through an API I'm making, using slim PHP and MySQL PDO. It gets the data perfectly, returning the one object I have in the database,

```
 [
        {
            "invId": "1",
            "invUid": "1",
            "invNavn": "Telt",
            "invRegistrert": "2020-11-29 16:44:21",
            "invPlassering": "Naustet",
            "invStatus": "U",
            "invVekt": "10",
            "invStørrelse": "{\"x\":\"10\",\"y\":\"10\",\"z\":\"10\"}",
            "invInnhold": "[1xTelt]",
            "invBilde": "",
            "invKommentar": null
        }
    ]
```

But when I attempt posting data using this code:

```
// Add Inventory
$app->post('/inventar/add', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    // Get Params From Request
    $navn = $request->getParam('navn');
    $uid = $request->getParam('uid');
    $plassering = $request->getParam('plassering');
    $vekt = $request->getParam('vekt');
    $størrelse = $request->getParam('størrelse');
    $innhold = $request->getParam('innhold');
    $bilde_path = $request->getParam('bilde_path');
    $kommentar = $request->getParam('kommentar');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO inventar (invNavn, invUid, invPlassering, invVekt, invStørrelse, invInnhold, invBilde, invKommentar) 
    VALUES (:invNavn, :invUid, :invPlassering, :invVekt, :invStørrelse, :invInnhold, :invBilde, :invKommentar) ";

    try {
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();
        // Prepare stmt
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        // Bind Params To Query
        $stmt->bindParam(':invNavn', $navn);
        $stmt->bindParam(':invUid', $uid);
        $stmt->bindParam(':invPlassering', $plassering);
        $stmt->bindParam(':invVekt', $vekt);
        $stmt->bindParam(':invStørrelse', $størrelse);
        $stmt->bindParam(':invInnhold', $innhold);
        $stmt->bindParam(':invBilde', $bilde_path);
        $stmt->bindParam(':invKommentar', $kommentar);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "Inventar Lagt Til"}}';

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}}';
    }
});
```

It returns {"error": {"text": SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined}},
It says parameter was not defines, but I don't understand what parameter isn't defined, some help with this would be much appreciated.
I'm sending a post request with this body.

```
   {
        "invUid": "2",
        "invNavn": "Telt",
        "invPlassering": "Naustet",
        "invVekt": "10",
        "invStørrelse": "{\"x\":\"10\",\"y\":\"10\",\"z\":\"10\"}",
        "invInnhold": "[1xTelt]",
        "invBilde": "",
        "invKommentar": null
    }
```

Comment: Your example of the POST request has keys `"invUid"`, `"invNavn"` and so on, but you grab you request params without the `inv` prefix:  `$navn = $request->getParam('navn');`. Have you checked what your variables actually hold?

Comment: This character `ø` looks suspicious.

Comment: @odan I think it should be alright, its utf8, might be a problem I'm not aware of tho